# Ajax doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

this code doesn't work in firefox, in chrome it works and I'm getting results

```js
console.log('send');
$.ajax({
  url: my_object.ajax_url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    action: 'sendPhone',
    phone: '23342342',
    city: 'sddsfsf',
  },
  beforeSend: function(){
    console.log('beforeSend');
  },
  success: function(msg){
    console.log('result = '+msg);
    return;
  },
});//end $.ajax
```

output in chrome
[image: Chrome]
and this is output in firefox
[image: Firefox]
Who knows why $.Ajax doesn't work?

It something weird happening in our forest... :(

Comment: change return to  return true?need more code

Comment: i think return is unnecessary and you have given comma after success block ends which seems to be unnecessary

Comment: Check whats actually coming back from the request in the network tab of the console. Also remove the `return` statement. It's completely redundant in your async `success` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`

```
console.log('send');
$.ajax({
  url: my_object.ajax_url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    action: 'sendPhone',
    phone: '23342342',
    city: 'sddsfsf',
  },
  beforeSend: function(){
    console.log('beforeSend');
  }
  })
  .success(function(msg){
    console.log('result = ' + msg);
  });
```

`